# Limiting the number of spawned headless Chrome processes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I've been using `chrome-launcher` and `chrome-remote-interface` to generate static images from JS-rendered page like so:

```
chromeLauncher.launch({
    chromeFlags: [
        '--window-size=1020,720',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless'
    ]
}).then(async function({port}) {
    const client = await CDP({port})   
    ...
})
```

It works well, but this happens in response to incoming http requests and I don't want to spawn infinite chromes. How can I best track and limit the number of processes generated, keeping in mind this is a standalone node script that is run anew each time?